# How do I pass a variable to a callback in puppeteer's $eval?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

The following code doesn't work due to a *ReferenceError* when trying to access `uid`. I understand that the `eval` code is running inside the browser's context and thus doesn't have access to this variable, but I don't know how to pass the variable's value regardless:

```
var uid = 'foo@example.com';
await page.$eval('#uid', el => el.value = uid);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The third argument of `page.$eval()` passes in arguments, so you would do:

```
await page.$eval('#uid', (el, _uid) => el.value = _uid, uid);
```

[`page.$eval()` docs as of Puppeteer 1.3.0](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/d244fce/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1):

> **page.$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])**
>
> - `selector` <string> A selector to query page for
> - `pageFunction` <function> Function to be evaluated in browser context
> - `...args` <...Serializable|JSHandle> Arguments to pass to `pageFunction`
> - returns: <Promise<Serializable>> Promise which resolves to the return value of `pageFunction`

Comment: A small correction, it should be:
`await page.$eval('#uid', (el, _uid) => el.value = _uid, uid);`